# Regex to match an URL

Tags: c#, regex

I'm new with regular expressions. I need to match the following lines:

1. /api/v1/user/[^/?#]+/users
2. /api/v1/user/some-id/users

My code is

```
url1="/api/v1/user/[^/?#]+/users";

url2="/api/v1/user/some-id/users";

var ll = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(url1, @"^("+Regex.Escape(url2)+"):");
```

Comment: Perhaps `/user` and `/roles` do not match. Did you mean `^(/api/v1/(?:user|roles)/[^/?#]+/users)`?

Comment: The first string parameter is the string to test and the 2nd is the pattern to match against, so swap them. Also, you don't want to escape either of your strings. `var ll = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(url2, @"^"+url1+"$");`

Also, your urls still won't match because they are still different, see @Thefourthbird's comment

Comment: @Thefourthbird .ya for users

Comment: As suggested by another user, remove the colon `:` If you are not referring to the capturing group in you code for example you could also omit the parenthesis. `^/api/v1/user/[^/?#]+/users` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PqJpqE/1)

Comment: @Ruzihm.i swapped, but still getting false as the answer.(i corrected that Thefourthbird comment)

Comment: Try it like this http://rextester.com/ECYH8918

Comment: can you give an example of what "some-id" is supposed to be? or is it literally "some-id"

Comment: @Thefourthbird 

`String url1="^/api/v1/user/[^/?#]+/users";
 String url2="/api/v1/user/134/users";
  var ll = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(url2, url1);`

code is working...Thanks
is it possible to match either user or role in third position
`String url1="^/api/v1/(user|role)/[^/?#]+/users";
 String url2="/api/v1/user/134/users";`

Comment: That is possible because the [alternation](http://rextester.com/ZJXD28929) would match either of them.

Comment: Why do you have those parantheses in your regex?

Comment: @Thefourthbird.thank you.anser is working

Comment: @vct You are welcome. I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, to match both `/api/v1/user/some-id/users` and `/api/v1/role/134/users`, use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

`^/api/v1/(?:user|role)/[^/?#]+/users`

```
String regex="^/api/v1/(?:user|role)/[^/?#]+/users";
String url2="/api/v1/user/some-id/users";
Console.WriteLine(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(url2, regex));
```

[C# demo](http://rextester.com/ZJXD28929)